# JavaFX Activate Datepicker dropdown

Tags: javafx, datepicker, fxml

How do I activate the the dropdown calendar of a datepicker when it is focused?

Letter.FXML

```
<DatePicker fx:id="letterDatePicker" editable="false" focusTraversable="false" layoutX="184.0" layoutY="174.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="178.0" promptText="Select date">
```

FXMLControllerLetter.java

```
@FXML
private void companyName(ActionEvent event)
{
    if(fxTxtCompanyName.getText().isEmpty())
    {
        Stage letterStage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle("Insufficient Data");
        alert.initOwner(letterStage);

        alert.setHeaderText("Lacking company name");
        alert.setContentText("Looks like you forgot to input the company name!");

        alert.showAndWait();
    }
    else
    {
        fxTxtCompanyName.setText(fxTxtCompanyName.getText().toUpperCase());
        letterDatePicker.requestFocus();
        letterDatePicker.show();
    }

}
```

Date Format Converter - I wanted the format of the datepicker to be "MMMM dd, yyyy" so I set the StringConverter to get my desired output format.

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) 
{
    // TODO
    fxLblCurrentDate.setText(dateNow());

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="DATE FORMAT CONVERTER">
    String pattern = "MMMM dd, yyyy";
    letterDatePicker.setConverter(new StringConverter<LocalDate>() 
    {
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);

        @Override
        public String toString(LocalDate date) 
        {
            if (date != null)
            {
                return dateFormatter.format(date);
            }
            else
            {
                return "";
            }
        }

        @Override
        public LocalDate fromString(String string) 
        {
            if (string != null && !string.isEmpty()) 
            {
                return LocalDate.parse(string, dateFormatter);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    });
    // </editor-fold>
}
```

Comment: I can't see any unusual line in the code.  Is there any listeners attached to datepicker? More precisely, is there any bindings or relations that datepicker involves in?

Comment: @Uluk Added the StringConverter for the DatePicker.

Comment: tried that on the code I have posted in the answer. Still nothing similar as you described, no enter key problem. Try to simplify your code and delete partially to determine which lines causing the problem.

Comment: @Uluk Biy Ok I guess I'm on my own now. At least now I know that .show() is the one what I'm looking for. Thank you for your time Uluk...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoke `show()` method of it. See implicit full example below:

```
@Override
public void start( Stage stage )
{

    final DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
    datePicker.setEditable( false );
    datePicker.setFocusTraversable( false );
    datePicker.setPromptText( "Select date" );
    datePicker.setPrefWidth( 170 );

    Button b = new Button( "choose date" );
    b.setOnAction( new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle( ActionEvent event )
        {
            datePicker.show();
            datePicker.requestFocus();
        }
    } );

    Scene scene = new Scene( VBoxBuilder.create().children( datePicker, b ).build(), 800, 600 );
    stage.setScene( scene );
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: I already tried the show() method before posting. It only fills the DatePicker with the system current date.

Comment: @Mark, posted full example where the button shows datepicker on click. And there is no filling or like so. Obviously you are filling it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the example. The drop down calendar works now but for reason unknown to me, it only works if I hold down the Enter key. The drop down calendar pulls back up when I let go of the Enter key. I made sure that the event is assigned to On Action and not in On Key Pressed.

Comment: @Mark, unfortunately it is nearly impossible to say anything without seeing your code.